# SQL - querying via a textbox which could take different values

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Developing a website and just trying to get back into the swing of (clever) SQL queries etc, my mind had totally gone tonight!

There is a website http://www.ufindus.com/ which has a textbox allowing you to enter either a place name or a postcode/zipcode.  I am trying to do something similiar but I am rubbish at SQL - so how do you construct an SQL statement that could potentially look at 2 columns (i.e. place and postcode) because you can't query both fields for the same value e.g

```
place = 'YORK' AND postcode = 'YORK'
```

or

```
place = 'YO21 5EA' AND postcode = 'YO21 5EA'
```

so do you have to put some logic in to be intelligent enough to detect whether it looks like a place name or a postcode - that just seems too complicated to me!! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an "OR" to get the job done.  For example,

place = 'YORK' or postcode = 'YORK'

You might also do better using the LIKE statement, as in

WHERE place LIKE 'YORK%' or postcode LIKE 'YORK%'

(this assumes both place and postcode are character-based columns)

Answer (score 3):

why not use OR instead of AND?

```
place = @textboxvalue OR post = @textboxvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with attempting to match on the place and postcode?  If I put in 'York' and (somewhere) that happens to be a valid postcode, I should get that result. As for preventing the same thing being entered twice, well, you can handle that on the validation prior to doing the database call.

Ah. Guess I was a bit slow on the up-take. Yes... what the others suggested is right, 'OR' is what you were looking for. I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first I'm assuming that you have a table with a mapping of postcodes to placenames.

Let's call this table '*postcode*' with columns '*postcode*' and '*postplace*'. Both of these are of a char-type.

Then.. whatever you do, make sure the input from the user is not part of dynamic sql. Make sure it is a **parameter**. Otherwise, you are inviting SQL injection attacks that can really ruin your day. This is **important**.

Our user input is in *@textboxstring*.

Given this, you can get the postcode and postplace like this:

`select @textboxstring = RTRIM(@textboxstring) + '%';
select postcode, postplace 
from postcode 
where postcode like @textboxstring or postplace like @textboxstring;`

Note that I'm modifying @textboxstring to get wildcard match with `like` without having to use dynamic sql.

If the postcode was integer, you would need to convert the input to int before executing the sql. So with a @textboxint as well, you could do this:

`select @textboxstring = RTRIM(@textboxstring) + '%';
select postcode, postplace 
from postcode 
where postcode = @textboxint or postplace like @textboxstring;`

Oh, and you need to handle that your search can have multiple results. You probably only want the first row.